# Can I store a small amount of data in a new Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've created a new Windows Service in Visual Studio using C#.  The service needs to run once per day, and I have a timer to check every hour to see if the time is correct for it to run the service code.

However, sometimes the server I am running can restart and it could miss this time.  So I want to be able to store the date and time of when the code was last run, so that every hour when I check the time I can also check to see if the code has been run today or if it still needs to be run.

So is there a way that I can store a date and time within a windows service without creating files or storing it within a database?

Comment: You could store a value in the registry if files or a database are out of the question...?

Comment: Hmm,  I suppose the registry doesn't sound like a terrible place.  It would go untouched there at least.  I'll look into that,  thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> The service needs to run once per day, and I have a timer to check every hour to see if the 
>   time is correct for it to run the service code.

And why the heck is this a windows service? COmmand line program, task scheduler, instead of wasting memory during the rest of the day.

> So is there a way that I can store a date and time within a windows service without creating 
>   files or storing it within a database?

In a variable. If the service stops it is gone as it is only in memory. But ruling out files (and database) that is all that is left.

That said, the whle approach is bad. Forget the service, make it a task and use the windows task scheduler.

Comment: It does a lot more than what I have explained here.  This is just one part of it.  Thats why its in a service.
But thanks,  I'll have a think about a variable.